# How to calculate e to the power of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, exponent

Just a quick question: how to calculate e to the power of a matrix in R:

```
#the matrix 
mm <- matrix(c(-0.447, 0.043, 0.232,-0.117), ncol=2)
#is this right?
exp(mm)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems not right to me. You need Taylor series. Did you try the function within `Matrix` package `?Matrix::expm`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @OceanSky_U. Is it this one: `Matrix::expm(mm)`? What will be a way to do it using just base R?

Comment: Yes, `Matrix::expm(mm)` should give you what you want. You can find more options of methods [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expm/expm.pdf). But I am not sure how to implement this with basic R.